# how to clear DNS cache in 22.04?

Tags: dns, cache

How is the DNS cache cleared in 22.04?

The method that worked in 20.04:

```
systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

no longer works.

Answer (score 37):

Newer versions of Ubuntu use this syntax (run as root or with `sudo`):

```
resolvectl flush-caches
```

*(This will also work in Ubuntu 20.04.)*

Comment: I'm on a freshly installed 22.04 and this command did not clear whatever DNS cache `dig` is using.

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu 22.04 users, follow the below command to flush DNS Cache(resolvectl) :

```
resolvectl flush-caches
```

To check the cache size run the below command:

```
resolvectl statistics
```